# Sysdeo Tomcat plugin not working in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, sysdeo

I upgraded my Eclipse to Luna and the Sysdeo tomcat toolbar won't show anymore. When I go to Window -> Customize Perspective, there is an entry com_sysdeo_tomcat_action_set, but it is greyed out and says that it is part of the null command group.

Comment: I just noticed that even removing the plugin from the plugins directory and the dropins directory, the com_sysdeo_tomcat_action_set entry is still there, so I don't really know why that is.

I also see lots of other entries that are greyed out and complain that they are part of the null command group.

Comment: I have downgraded back to Juno because I don't know how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  Fixed by downloading the very newest (21 June 2014) Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin from http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html.

The downloaded file is named tomcatPluginV331.zip; from that file, extract the com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.1.jar file into your luna eclipse\dropins folder.

Then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The Sysdeo Tomcat plugin documentation for the lastest version (3.3) states
Works with Eclipse 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the latest (3.3.1) plugin working in Eclipse Luna. There's a fork of the original plugin, called TomcatPlugin, available through the marketplace that also includes support for Tomcat 8.x. Project home is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatplugin/.

Comment: this one work with the latest eclipse neon 2016, bravo